# "Explicit", "classified", "graphic" - did these words originate as abbreviations of longer phrases?

Tags: etymology

*Explicit* means clearly stated. *Classified* means assigned to a class. *Graphic* means pictorial.
But these words have second meanings (respectively: offensive, secret, depicting something violent). 
Can these be regarded as some form of abbreviated meaning/phrase? How are they named, if so? What are other examples?

Like "sexually explicit", "classified as top secret" (or other such designation) and "graphic violence" got abbreviated?

Comment: Great question although I'm not entirely agreeing with your second meanings...  Aren't the 'second' meanings: Of 'classified' -  *restricted access*; of 'graphic' - *excessive and shocking*; and of 'explicit' - *pornographically sexual*?

Comment: Aren't they at least related to euphemisms?

Comment: The words are not euphemisms, but are "nicknames", as it were, of longer phrases which are "clinical descriptions", to pull a term out of the air.  They only have the secondary meanings because of their associations with the longer phrases.

Comment: @Dan - The applicable definition of *graphic* is "vividly realistic" (MW).  And, of course, *classified* means having a classification, while *explicit* means "fully revealed or expressed without vagueness, implication, or ambiguity" (MW).

Comment: @HotLicks This phenomenon happens in other languages as well. Consider Polish "element" which besides the obvious meaning can describe (uncountable) hooligans, contracted from communist propaganda buzzword "element przestępczy" - "criminal element [of the society]".

Comment: @MichałB. -- Certainly terms such as "criminal element" are known in the US, but to date "element" has not acquired a "taint" from such an association.

Comment: I had the exact same question on my mind, believe you me! I don't know about the other two but Wikipedia has an [acceptable write-up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphic_violence) on why Graphic is used to describe violent/explicit content.

Comment: @BiscuitBoy - *Graphic* is used because it means "vividly or plainly shown or described".  It's a definition of the word.

Comment: @HotLicks - The core meaning for 'graphic' (OED) is ***of or pertaining to drawing or painting*** and ***producing by words the effect of a picture; vividly descriptive, life-like.***  The meaning you are quoting is the second meaning as described by the OP (and me!) below - ***providing or conveying full, unexpurgated detail; expressly stated or represented; explicit, esp. in the depiction of sex or violence (OED)***.

Comment: @Dan - Depending on which dictionary you look at you get another definition along the lines of "vividly or plainly shown or described".  I'm sure this definition existed before "graphic sex" and "graphic violence" became idiomatic.

Comment: @HotLicks - the point for me is that calling something 'graphic' these days can carry implications of *extremeness* (especially sex and violence) NOT part of the usual meaning of graphic.  This usage, when people say 'graphic' as a shorthand euphemism for the extremes of sex and violence they would rather not describe (also not an original use of 'graphic')  is the 'second meaning' referred to in the OP.

Comment: If you look at the use of ["quite graphic"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=quite+graphic&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cquite%20graphic%3B%2Cc0) you will see that it's been a common term for two hundred years, and, aside from slowly acquiring more innuendo over the past half-century, it's manner of use has not changed very much.  From 1831: "The honorable mover of the resolution was somewhat exuberant in his investigation on this topic, and quite graphic in his descriptions."

Answer (score 1):

The way these meanings got attached to the words is speakers using shorthand and listeners making assumptions based on past experience.

So people said “[sexually] explicit” enough times that the word explicit gained the additional meaning “[sexually] explicit.” Same with your other examples.

However, keep in mind that when you say “graphic [violence]” I hear “graphic” because I sometimes work as a graphic artist. Context matters.

Answer (score -1):

There are times when we'd rather not say precisely what we mean/know (e.g. detailed descriptions of illness and accident).  At such times we can use euphemisms - *figures of speech which consist in the substitution of a word or expression of comparatively favourable implication or less unpleasant associations, instead of the harsher or more offensive one that would more precisely designate what is intended* (OED).

The '**second meanings**' of 'explicit', 'classified' and 'graphic' would seem to me, at least some of the time, to be euphemisms.  Notice that when they are used euphemistically their meaning is different to their usual, dictionary definition:

*Would that movie be OK for the kids ? Hmm, I don't think so it was a rom-com and some of the scenes were pretty **explicit**.*  (i.e. too much sex)

(Mates chatting) *So, how often have you been pulled over for speeding? Sorry, that information's **classified***. (i.e. none of your business)

*He described the accident, **graphically**.* (i.e. in shocking and excessive detail)

Comment: Except that that use of *graphic* is not euphemistic.  You're just assuming the wrong meaning.

Comment: @HotLicks - I think I'd argue that the more recent definition of 'graphic' -   *providing or conveying full, unexpurgated detail; expressly stated or represented; explicit, esp. in the depiction of sex or violence* (OED), is a use that was, originally, euphemistic but has become standard.  'Graphic' did not start out as a word with this meaning.